# Jaxb, avoid duplicate xml tag

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I'm facing a problem with my implementation of Jaxb java classes. My xml response should be like:

```
 <rootElement attr1="value1" attr2="value2">
      <child> childValue </child>
 </rootElement>
```

this is my java classes:

```
 @XmlRootElement
 public class RootElement {
     private String attr1;
     private String attr2;
     private Child child;

     @XmlAttribute
     public String getAttr1() {
         return attr1;
     }

     public void setAttr1(String attr1) {
         this.attr1 = attr1;
     }

     @XmlAttribute
     public String getAttr2() {
         return attr2;
     }

     public void setAttr2(String attr2) {
         this.attr2 = attr2;
     }

     public void setChild(Child c) {
         child = c;
     }

     @XmlElement
     public Token getChild() {
         return child;
     }
 }
```

and this is Child:

```
 public class Child {

     private String child;

     public Child() {

     }

     public void setChild(String child) {
         this.child = child;
     }

     public String getChild() {
         return child;
     }

 }
```

I obtain this xml:

```
 <rootElement attr1="value1" attr2="value2">
      <child><child>childValue</child></child>
 </rootElement>
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first `<child>` is produced for `child` variable of **RootElement** class.
The second `<child>` is produced for `child` variable of **Child** class.

If you can make sure there is only one mapping in **Child** class, you can add `@XmlAnyElement` to `child` variable. JAXP will not produce second `<child>` element.

```
public class Child {

    @XmlAnyElement
    private String child;

    public Child() {
    }

    public void setChild(String child) {
        this.child = child;
    }
    public String getChild() {
        return child;
    }
}
```